# ¿Como guardar los check de un checkbox a la base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, wpf

Desarrollo una aplicacion en WPF con C#.
Tengo una ventana que contiene un Combobox en donde los Items estan compuestos de Checkbox con un resultado foreach de una tabla.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Como guardo en la base de datos con LINQ, los check del checkbox que estan dentro del Combobox ?

```
-XAML <ComboBox x:Name="Cbx_Programas">
                        <ComboBoxItem >
                            <CheckBox x:Name="Cbox_Programas"/>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>

-Code-Behind foreach (var c in dbContext.Software)
        {
            Cbox_Programas = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
            Cbox_Programas.Content = c.Nombre;
            Cbx_Programas.Items.Add(Cbox_Programas);
        }
```

[image: Este es mi Combobox con los Checkbox]

Comment: No queda del todo claro lo que intentas hacer, agrega la estructura de la clase de ef donde pretendas insertar la información además

Comment: Supongo que no implementas el patrón MVVM (sería mucho mas fácil si lo implementaras). Por otra parte, desde mi punto de vista no ayuda mucho que uses directamente las entidades en el code behind, es mucho mas fácil si creas estructuras con la información que te traes desde la bdd (de las entidades) y que puedas enlazar al control.

Answer (score 1):

No deberias acceder al control checkbox para tener la seleccion, deberias bindear los datos y acceder a los datos para ver si esta seleccionada la opcion

[Using Checkbox in Combo Box](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/using-checkbox-in-combo-box/)

basicamente defines

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb" Margin="5" Height="35" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisited}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

veras como se usa el `Binding` para asignar los datos, defines una clase

```
public class TripInfo
{
    public Boolean IsVisited{ get; set; }

    public String Name{ get; set; }
}
```

y la asignas como datasurce del combo

```
List<TripInfo> tripList = new List<TripInfo>();
tripList.Add(new TripInfo() { IsVisited = false, Name= "item1"});
tripList.Add(new TripInfo() {IsVisited = false, Name = "item2"});

cmb.ItemsSource = tripList;
```

la idea es que iteres la lista de objeto para saber cuales estan marcado.

Nota: Los nombres de las clases y propiedades son solo de ejemplo, debes adaptarlo a tu caso

Comment: Yo creo que lo ideal es que la clase TripInfo implemente INotifyPropertyChanged, y que en vez de una lista sea ObservableCollection.

Comment: Si esta implementando MVVM seria lo recomendado, pero en este caso no creo que este implementando este patron por eso el source se asigna directo al combobox por medio del ItemsSource y no como parte de un ViewModel